# Long-horizon predictive regressions

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting

So for an assignment I have to compute some long-horizon predictive regressions. Univariate, bivariate and multiple.

I collected all my monthly data (From 1963:07 to 2016:12) for the dependend and the independend variables and my task is now to compute monthly long-horizon predictive regressions with the forecasting horizons 1,6,9,12,24,36 and 48 months. I need the R² (slop estimates) and t-statistics for each of those horizons.

So I only know how to do basic linear regressions and I am completly lost now. I have no idea how to compute those different forecasting horizons and get the meausures.

So does anyone know the right solution to my problem or could help me?

Comment: The R-Squared is not the slope estimate, but the percentage of variance explained.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for this information, i confused something there! 
But then again, how can i get the slope estimates for each independend variable at those different horizons?

Comment: Is this for a class?  Have you tried asking whoever gave you the assignment?